# I am trying to execute a powershell script in python that references another powershell script

Tags: python, windows, powershell

I am attempting to execute a powershell script in python. I was able to do this using a simple 'Hello World' script to prove that it works, but I now need to execute another script written by a retired coworker. I am not very familiar with powershell scripts. All scripts are currently located in the same directory. The script in question invokes another powershell script. Also this does work correctly when invoked from the powershell command line.
The python script looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
import subprocess, sys

cmd = 'powershell.exe'
dir = 'C:\Agent\\agentStatus.ps1'

p = subprocess.Popen([cmd,
              dir],
              stdout=sys.stdout)
p.communicate()
```

The powershell script looks like this:

```
Write-Host -NoNewLine "Agent service is "
./TSagentService.ps1 -Status
if ((Get-Process "endpoint_runner" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Write-Output "Agent is Not Running"
} else {
    Write-Output "Agent is Running"
}
```

The error I get when invoked is this:

```
./TSagentService.ps1 : The term './TSagentService.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\agentStatus.ps1:3 char:1
+ ./TSagentService.ps1 -Status
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (./TSagentService.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Do I need to rewrite the original script to get the referenced script to invoke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could replace `./TSagentService.ps1` with `$PSScriptRoot/TSagentService.ps1` in the script in order to reliably target a script in the same folder as the enclosing script, there may be other code in the script(s) that assumes that the script's own location is also the working directory, so **you're better off setting the working directory to the target script's directory explicitly**.

If you're using *PowerShell (Core) v6+* with its [`pwsh.exe` CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), you can take advantage of its new `-WorkingDirectory` (`-wd`) parameter to do so; e.g. (using no-shell / `cmd.exe` / PowerShell syntax):

```sh
pwsh -wd c:/path/to -file c:/path/to/script.ps1
```

In *Windows PowerShell*, use [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)'s `-Command` (`-c`) parameter to place a `Set-Location` call before the invocation of your script; e.g.:

```sh
powershell -c "Set-Location c:/path/to; & ./script.ps1"
```

Applied your Python code, which calls `powershell.exe`:

```py
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
import subprocess, sys, pathlib

cmd = 'powershell.exe'
script = 'C:\Agent\\agentStatus.ps1'
dir = pathlib.Path(script).parent

p = subprocess.Popen(
  [
    cmd,
    '-noprofile',
    '-c',
    'Set-Location \"{}\"; & \"{}\"'.format(dir, script)
  ],
  stdout=sys.stdout
)
p.communicate()
```

Note that I've also added `-noprofile`, which is good practice for non-interactive calls.